# "CL : warning : The Pattern Matching algorithm is not fully MBCS compatible", warning in VS 2013. What does it mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting this warning for four .cpp files out of about 200 in a VS 2013 C++ project which is targeted at x64.

There are no line numbers with the warning, so I have no idea why I'm getting the warning on just several files.

What does it mean?

Comment: Try bisection: Copy each half of the file into a new file, and compile both. In this way, you can find the smallest snippet which still exhibits the problem. Include that in the question.

Comment: Not so simple, there are header files, and I can't split those up. I'm more interested in what the warning means.